# Why do transparent objects become opaque when animating canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, transparency

I'm trying to do a js app that would basically move some balls on a canvas element. I set the `context.fillStyle = "rgba(12, 34, 56, 0.2)";` the problem is that the balls become opaque from transparent after a short period of time. How can I maintain their transparency and why do they become opaque?

here is simplified version of my code:

```
function startScript(){
var layer1       = document.getElementById("layer1");
var context1     = layer1.getContext("2d");

var posX = 5;

context1.fillStyle = "rgba(12, 34, 56, 0.05)";

animate();

function animate() {

    posX+=3;

    context1.arc(posX, 200, 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
    context1.fill();

    // request new frame
    requestAnimFrame(function() {
        animate();
    });
}
}

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the fillstyle in the animate() function, maybe the context is reset between frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to use context1.beginPath before your new line draws**

Otherwise, the context remembers and redraws the previous arc in addition to the new arc.

Also, you should do context1.closePath() after drawing a circle-arc.

Otherwise the context is drawing an unclosed arc instead of a circle.

```
context1.beginPath();
context1.arc(posX, 200, 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
context1.closePath();
context1.fill();
```